# Can't open SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration

Tags: development, 2007, central-administration

I'm new to SharePoint.

I have installed Project Server 2007 on my Windows 2003 server. It worked previously, but yesterday after i installed some Microsoft updates, I can't open SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration. I'm using IIS 6.0, .NET Framework 3.0 with IE7.

This is the error message that i received when i click SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Root element is missing.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\7150\web.config
>   Line: 0

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3614

Answer (score 1):

As the others have referred to, certain updates require your to complete a command line update to SharePoint to finalize the update.

The error you are seeing is different though.  Chances are, your web.config file was corrupted.  I would look there first.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when the SharePoint restore process is interrupted while the process is running. I suggest two solutions to this problem.

Restart the WSS timer service and then try to restore the backup
If this does not work, then try this

Re-run the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard and then try to run the restore process.
Hope this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

you will need to run psconfig from an administrator command prompt as detailed below to complete the update.

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait –force
```

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100821095923/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepoint/archive/2010/06/22/installing-kb938444.aspx)